# string lists in C: python-like shortcuts?

Tags: python, c, arrays, string

I'm returning to programming in C after years of using Python.  One thing I'm wondering what tools are best in C to write something similar to the Python:

list1=["foo","bar"]

The closest I've come up with is something like:

```
char * list1[2];
list1[0]="foo";
list1[1]="bar";
```

This works fine but is a little unwieldy.  I've seen some C++ examples online that use {}, and I'm wondering whether there's a way of getting this idiom (or something similar) to work in pure C.

Comment: Downvoting without a comment is very unpolite!

Comment: I upvoted to cancel it, I think this is a decent question even though it is duplicated everywhere.

Answer (score 5):

That should work on C too. Try,

```
const char * list1[] = { "foo", "bar" };
```

Comment: OK, it looks like I've confused myself about the correct syntax for initializing this type of variable.

Your syntax works beautifully.  But how would I initialize list1 at the beginning of a function?

Comment: Just don't get too comfortable and try to write an `append` function which goes off the end of your statically allocated array...

Comment: @user1521655 I am confused. You can write the same code at the beginning of a function. I could help you further if you can explain more about what you actually meant.

Comment: If we were talking about an integer, I'd mean:
    int x; \\this part
    x=1; \\not this part

Comment: Can you please post small snippet at pastebin.com of what you wish to do?

Comment: That's something totally different. `char *[]` is not same as `char **`. With that said, initialization and assignment are two different things. What you are doing is an assignment which is not possible using initializer lists. Initialization is done during variable declaration itself but not later. You have to do http://pastebin.com/5C32867W like this in later case.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something very similar to initialize an *array* in C (lists don't exist by default)

```
char * myStringArray[4] = { "This", "is", "my", "array" };
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a caveat: when you are initialising from a string like this you have to remember the trailing nul byte is there.

Also it's good practice to fully qualify the constness of the pointers: `const char *const list1[]={"foo","bar"};` (assuming it really is an array of const pointers to const data).